# Warning: New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available - How do I update?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cocoapods

I was running my simulator and in my debug console, I got the following message:

New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available

How do I update to the latest version? I tried to do sudo gem pod install, but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these [instructions to upgrade](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#upgrade_from_an_earlier_version) an existing project to the most recent version of the Google Maps SDK for iOS.

If you previously installed the Google Maps SDK for iOS from a zip file containing a static framework:

- Remove all references to the previous framework from your Xcode project.
- Follow the instructions [above](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_1_get_the_la) to install the Google Maps SDK for iOS using CocoaPods.
- Make any necessary changes as a result of the upgrade. See the [release notes][3] for a list of the changes in each release.
- Clean and rebuild your project by selecting **Product** > **Clean** and then **Product** > **Build**.

If you previously installed the Google Maps SDK for iOS from the Google-Maps-iOS-SDK pod:

- Change your pod name to GoogleMaps.
- Run pod install.
- Make any necessary changes as a result of the upgrade. See the release notes for a list of the changes in each release.
- Clean and rebuild your project by selecting **Product** > **Clean** and then **Product** > **Build**.

If you previously installed the Google Maps SDK for iOS from the GoogleMaps pod:

- Check your Podfile for any version limiter, and ensure you remove or update the version to ensure you get the version you need. See the release notes for a list of version numbers.
- Run pod update.
- Make any necessary changes as a result of the upgrade. See the release notes for a list of the changes in each release.
- Clean and rebuild your project by selecting **Product** > **Clean** and then **Product** > **Build**.

**Note**: Versions 1.9.2 and earlier of the Google Maps SDK for iOS were available as a zip file containing a static framework. There was also the option to install recent versions from a CocoaPods pod. From version 1.10.0 onwards, the Google Maps SDK for iOS is available for installation only via CocoaPods.

Answer (score 0):

*sudo gem pod install* will install *Cocoapods*.

What you need to do is update the pods in your project.

You can do it by executing the command *pod update* or *pod install* in the folder in which your *Podfile* is located.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the below steps to update any SDK which got installed using CocoaPods:

- Open terminal
- Type cd /yourProjectFolderPath and press enter
- Type pod update POD NAME and press enter
- E.g: pod update GoogleMaps

That's all. A new version of the SDK will be updated in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If after `pod install` nothing updated, run `pod update`.